# How to setRestartStrategy use TableEnvironment?

Tags: java, apache-flink

```
TableEnvironment tableEnv = TableEnvironment.create(
        EnvironmentSettings
                .newInstance()
                .build());
                
tableEnv
   .getConfig()
   .getConfiguration()
   .setString("parallelism.default", "3");
```

I use `TableEnvironment` to `executeSql`, how to `setRestartStrategy`?

Answer (score 0):

A good approach might be to put this configuration into `flink-conf.yaml`. E.g.,

```yaml
restart-strategy: fixed-delay
restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts: 3
restart-strategy.fixed-delay.delay: 10s
```

https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/docs/deployment/config/#fault-tolerance

Answer (score 0):

I didn't find a reference on the java documentation but there is one on the [python documentation for flink](https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-release-1.12/dev/python/table-api-users-guide/table_environment.html#statebackend-checkpoint-and-restart-strategy). Otherwise, just configure it on `flink-conf.yaml` as @David answered.

```
tEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration().setString("restart-strategy", "fixed-delay");
tEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration().setString("restart-strategy.fixed-delay.attempts", "3");
tEnv.getConfig().getConfiguration().setString("restart-strategy.fixed-delay.delay", "30s");
```